# request.env["omniauth.auth"] returns nil if not called as argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, request, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I'm trying to do a simple omniauth call with facebook. Everything works fine if I capture the request hash like this:

```
def facebook
    user = User.from_facebook(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
```

But if I try to save the request hash in a variable, I get request = nil. e.g.:

```
def facebook
  omni_request = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.from_facebook(omni_request)
  if user.persisted?
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

The above example blows up because request is nil, and I can't call env on something that is nil.

Does anyone have any idea why request would be nil when called outside of the `from_facebook` class method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the third line should be : user = User.from_facebook(omni_request) ?

Comment: So, the problem was that I called my variable request in my actual code, which was overwriting the request ... So technically you were right, so I'll give it to you.